# JAVA XML Signature with PKCS11 provider HSM

Tags: java, pkcs#11, xml-signature

I'm trying to sign a `XML` using a private key in my `HSM` but I'm getting an error because the private key contains "sensitive" information so now I'm trying to use my `PKCS11` provider to sign.

I'm using `Luna JSP provider`.

That's how I generate my signature using a private key and from what I understand with my error com.safenetinc.luna.exception.LunaException: Cannot access sensitive attributes, I need to use a `PKCS11` provider to be able to sign inside my `HSM` but I don't see how to implement it with a `XMLSignatureFactory`.

```
XMLSignatureFactory fac;
try {
  fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());
}
catch(InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

Reference ref;
SignedInfo si;
try {
  ref = fac.newReference("",
                         fac.newDigestMethod(xmldss.getDigestMethod(), null),
                         Collections.singletonList(fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED,
                                                                    (TransformParameterSpec) null)),
                         null,
                         null);

  si = fac.newSignedInfo(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(xmldss.getCanonicalizationMethod(),
                                                       (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
                         fac.newSignatureMethod(xmldss.getSignatureMethod(), null),
                         Collections.singletonList(ref));
}
catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document document;
try {
  document = (dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlDocumentStream));
}
catch(SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(keyPair.getPrivate(), document.getDocumentElement());
dsc.setDefaultNamespacePrefix(xmldss.getDigitalSignerPrefix());

XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, buildKeyInfo(fac, signatureInfos));
try {
  signature.sign(dsc);
}
catch(MarshalException | XMLSignatureException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please show what you are doing and the exact errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging in `DOMXMLSignature` I found that the property `org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.SignatureProvider` can be use to set a provider.

So my fix was to do

```
Provider lunaProvider = Security.getProvider("LunaProvider");
dsc.setProperty("org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.SignatureProvider", lunaProvider);
```

Comment: @baskwo
Nice one Nick.
Definitely helped me!

Comment: I'm always there to help LD :P

Comment: it works with Safenet provider as well. Thank you!